# Installing OpenFX plugins

Tags: 18.04

Running ubuntu Mate 18.04.
Recently purchased an OpenFX plugin to use in an application I know works with and is compatible with OpenFX.

However, having no luck installing and getting the plugin recognized by the program.

I tried 2 locations

1 In the application bundle

```
/home/<username>/<application>/Plugins/OFX/
```

and

2 in a manually created folder here

```
/usr/Plugins/OFX/
```

Neither seems to work.

What is the recommended way to install OpenFX plugins so that they are recognized by more than 1 application?
Is there some type of environment PATH setting that needs setting?

Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Op
Thru trial and error discovered that the application, Natron, is very particular about OpenFX plugin location

Plugin bundles must go here

```
/home/<username>/Natron2/Plugins/OFX/Natron
```